# Let pX(x) = x/15, x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, zero elsewhere, be the pmf of X. Find P(X = 1 or 2), P( 1/2 < X < 5/2 ), and P(1 ≤ X ≤ 2).

Tags: probability, statistics

For the first one, the P(X=1 or 2)=1/15+2/15=1/5 and I get that part.
Is the answer 1/5 for the other two as well, because in both cases X can only be 1 and 2, or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $\frac15$ for the other two parts. The intersection of the given ranges with $X$'s support is the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.